# Tools to create installers or setup programs in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, visual-studio-2015

After I built a good WPF application in C# and willing to work with that technology, I knew that my software development tools with Visual Studio Community 2015 RC are not enough without a tool for creating setup programs.

So, I'd tried to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects but unfortunately, Microsoft Visual Studio Professional which is not free, is required to be able to install that extension!

[image: [Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects Requirement]

I've also tried to install the release version of WiX Toolset v3.9 R2 but it's not compatible with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9

Comment: It's June, 2016. Thanks to Microsoft's shift to more open policies, the linked `installer` now can be installed on _free_ Community Edition of VS-2015

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For those who are preparing to use Visual Studio 2015, here's what I found, the latest builds of WiX v3.10 that [can be downloaded from this link](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/), are compatible for Visual Studio 2015 as what WiX toolset replied on their tweets: https://twitter.com/wixtoolset/status/597796279729528833

> @5ervant latest builds of WiX v3.10 support @VisualStudio 2015.
>
> However, VS doesn't allow extensions to install in Express SKUs.

The [WiX v3.10.0.1519 from this link](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/v3-10-0-1519/), is tried and tested!

Comment: I maintain an open source WiX authoring tool that rides on top of WiX.  I've tested VS2015 CE, WiX 3.10 and my latest IsWiX 3.0 release against this stack and it works fine.  This was important to me because over the years I've blogged about authoring MSIs using free tools such as Visual Studio Integrated Shell and InstallShield Limited Edition or WiX and IsWiX.

Comment: Upon installing the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects extension in VS 2015 (not the RC version), it is working well!

Answer (score 7):

I encountered a similar issue to the OP; so I'll put my story here in the hope it will help somebody.

At first I attempted to install "Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects" in the latest version of Visual Studio 2015 Community via the "Extensions and Updates" functionality in VS2015 itself, it seemed to go fine and completed successfully, I restarted VS to no avail, the project templates were nowhere to be found, and old web setup projects weren't recognised grrr...

Had a mosey around google and found lots of people were experiencing similar issues (that's how I came across this SO post)...

I thought hmm... maybe just a dodgy install... but I thought this time I would download it myself via https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9 instead of from within VS2015.... downloaded it, (closed VS), then ran the installer, VS restarted... now when I go to New Project > Installed > Other Project Types > Visual Studio Installer all my old setup templates are available... and now VS2015 recognises my old web setup projects in existing solutions too.

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that while installing VS2015 i had VS2010 installed.

Comment: I also have VS2010 pro installed, did you encounter any issues when setting up VS2015 parallel to VS2010 ?

Comment: @Ahmed Suprisingly none. They seem to work well together... I've had them both installated for some six months now and nothing has cropped up so far.

Answer (score 2):

This is just to refine your recipe:

(1) Launch RegEdit

(2) if win32:
    Select key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0"
    if win64:
    Select key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0"

(3) In that key/subkey, you must create two new subkeys:
    "professional"
    "vscore"

(4) In each of the subkeys you have just created create a REGSZ value (=string) with the name "Install" and value "1" (yes: "1" is a string!)